# Find the continuous function $f$ with domain $\mathbb C$ such that it's differentiable on $x^2-y^2=1$ but is not differentiable at other points

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

Find the continuous function $f$ with domain $\mathbb C$ such that it's differentiable on $x^2-y^2=1$ but is not differentiable at other points of $\mathbb C$.

---

I assume $f=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, all points on $x^2-y^2=1$ are in the form $(x,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$ or $(x,-\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$, So if $f$ is going ot be differentiable at $(x,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$ then $$u_x(x,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})=v_y(x,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$$
$$u_y(x,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})=-v_x(x,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$$

And for points in the form $(x,-\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$
$$u_x(x-,\sqrt{x^{2}-1})=v_y(x,-\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$$
$$u_y(x,-\sqrt{x^{2}-1})=-v_x(x,-\sqrt{x^{2}-1})$$

How does that help to find $f$?

Comment: Some details are missing. What is to codomain of $f$? What is $x$ and $y$ in the expression $x^2-y^2=1$? If this is the real and the imaginary part of the argument, this should be clearly stated. Also, it is said "Find the continuous function f", which tends to say that it is unique. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Perhaps try something that is $0$ with $0$ derivative on that hyperbola?

Comment: Let $g$ be a differentiable function and $h$ a not differentiable function. Then take $f = g + (x^2-y^2-1)*h$. Would that work ?

Comment: @ M. Wind, Then how do we show that such function is differentiable at $x^2-y^2=1$ and is not differentiable at the other points of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @ M. Wind $f$ would not be necessarily complex differentiable on the unit circle, it would be differentiable within the domain of the unit circle. The OP is correct you need to use the Cauchy Riemann equations to show complex differentiablility.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

We want a function, $f(x,y)= u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ such that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ on the unit circle and fails those equations off of the unit circle. Well, if I want $u_x=v_y$ when every $x^2+y^2=1$, then lets try to manipulate the $x^2+y^2=1$ to fit that equation, maybe $x^2=1-y^2$? So we see to set $u_x = x^2$ and $v_y = 1-y^2$. We then arrive at

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \left(y-\frac{1}{3}y^3\right) i$$

Double check that this satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations for every point on the unit circle (i.e., $x^2+y^2=1$), but fails for every point that is not on the unit circle (i.e., $x^2+y^2\not=1$). This follows pretty easily since the second equation $u_y=-v_x$ is trivially $0=0$, so you only have to check the first equation.

Note: The word "the" in the phrase "the continuous function" is incorrect. There are clearly many continuous functions that work.

Comment: Why do we want a function $f$ that satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations on the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, but fails them off of it?  My reading of the question is that we want a continuous function $f$ that is differentiable --- it's unclear to me if real-differentiability or complex-differentiability is meant --- precisely on the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought is was the unit circle. Change the plus to a minus. The technique would not change.